# Why does $(a-2b)\times (3a+2b) = a\times (3a+2b) - 2b \times(3a+2b)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Let $\textbf{a},\textbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be such that $|\textbf{a}| = |\textbf{b}|$ and the angle between them is $45º$. We had a test where we should find the answer of $(\textbf{a}-2\textbf{b})\times(3\textbf{a}+2\textbf{b})$. The answer was $8 (\textbf{a}\times \textbf{b})$, but I couldn't understand how:
$$
(\textbf{a}-2\textbf{b})\times(3\textbf{a}+2\textbf{b}) = \textbf{a}\times(3\textbf{a}+2\textbf{b}) - 2\textbf{b}\times(3\textbf{a}+2\textbf{b}) \\= 3 (\textbf{a}\times \textbf{a}) + 2 (\textbf{a}\times \textbf{b})
- 6 (\textbf{b}\times \textbf{a}) - 4 (\textbf{b}\times \textbf{b}) = 8 (\textbf{a}\times \textbf{b})
$$
Can anybody explain the part above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that $a\times a=0$, $b\times b=0$ and $a\times b=-b\times a$. I don't think you need $|a|=|b|$ for this proof.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. I understood a×b=−b×a for third part but for the second part, can you explain it more? I don't get it! feel free to laugh :D

Comment: :D :D $a\times b=|a| |b| \sin{\theta} n$ where $n$ is the vector perpendicular to the plane containing $a$, $b$ by right hand rule. $\theta$ is the angle between them. If $a=b$, $\theta=0$. So $a\times a=0$.

Comment: But what if θ = 45? can you explain the line step by step? I'm new in these subjects.

Comment: OK. The first term $a\times a=|a| |a| \sin{\theta} n$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $a$, which must be 0. The last term $b\times b=|b| |b| \sin{\theta} n$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $b$ and $b$, which must be 0 too. Is it clear now? Let me know if not.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.